# How to reposition and rescale Alaska and Hawaii in a shapefile using QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have barely used QGIS at all but I am trying to produce a colored map (based on opioid overdose rates) in Python using a county level shapefile from the Census Bureau. What I would like to do is just edit this shapefile so that I can call it directly in Python.

I can move the states and their respective counties around just fine but I am running into trouble when I go to rescale the counties. In the geometry generator I have the following:

[image]

but when I try to rescale the counties I get the following:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?

I don't know how to create another layer and manipulate things that way. I also read about trying an inset but I don't know what that is or how to go about it either. I mean no disrepect to the actual geometries here, I'm a data scientist who wants a nice looking map.

Comment: Inset map are the way to go. tutorial : https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/making_a_map.html

Comment: What J.R. says. Don't mess up the data, just display it differently.

Comment: Or just display them in the print layout if you need to create a printout or a pdf for instance.